# Solidity: Declaration Error: identifier not found or not unique. mapping(string=> team) teams; ^_ _^

Tags: solidity, declaration

This is my first time to write a computer programming language and it's a smart contract.

After finish, I pressed compile, and it shows the following error: DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
mapping(string=> team) teams;

^_ _^

Please anyone help me to find out what is the problem?
My smart contract as below:

```
// spdx-license-identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

contract Database {
   
 struct Team {
        string engineer;
        mapping (string=>uint) numbers;
    }

    mapping(string=>team) teams;

    function addTeams(string calldata teamName, string calldata engineer) public {
        Team storage team = teams [teamName];
        team.engineer = engineer;
    }

    function addDrawingNumber(string calldata teamName, string calldata engineerName, uint number) public {
        Team storage team = teams [teamName];
        team.numbers[engineerName] = number;
    }
    
    function getDrawingNumber(string calldata teamName, string calldata engineerName) public view returns (uint) {
        Team storage team = teams [teamName];
        return team.numbers[engineerName]
   ; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solidity is a case-sensitive language. You have defined a struct type `Team` (capital `T`) - but in the mapping you're trying to use a type `team` (lowercase `t`), which is not defined.

Solution: Unify the case sensitivity.

```
struct Team {
    string engineer;
    mapping (string=>uint) numbers;
}

mapping(string=>Team) teams;
```

Comment: Thanks Petr, I tried your method, and it works, so there is no more compile error. However, then it shows LINTER three results: First Error: Compiler version ^0.7.0 does not satisfy the r semver requirement.

Comment: The second Linter results Error: Contract name must be in CamelCase; this I already change the contract name. But the third Linter results Error: Explicitly mark visibility of state. This indicate line 9: mapping(string=>team) teams; but I don't know how to make it explicitly.

Comment: @Bradley Default visibility for a storage property is `internal`, so can you mark it explicitly as `mapping(string=>Team) internal teams;` ... I'm not sure how to resolve the version issue in the linter.

Comment: I wonder if there is no compile error, does that mean this smart contract still can works even there are some warnings and linter result errors?

Comment: @Bradley Linters usually focus on code style, optimization, and security. While compiler checks for validity of the code. So these are two separate things, both useful for something else... Just note that even if both linter and compiler show no errors, the contract still might "not work as expected" due to runtime errors (e.g. trying to access an array item 1 while the array is empty) or logical errors (e.g. subtracting instead of adding numbers).